# How can I view and change the hdmi refresh rate in windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, hdmi, refresh-rate

I have ordered the new Seiki U-Vision cable, which has a chip that upscales 1080p at 30hz to 4K. I will need to view and probably change the hdmi output in windows 8.1. I have searched "systems", but was unable to find a way to make this change or even view the current output rate.

Answer (score 0):

To view and or change your refresh rates you can access it by right clicking on your desktop and clicking personalize,  there will be a drop down menu that will display all of your available refresh rates.  These are dependant on your display device though so you may run into some secondary issues using a cable to manipulate things.